# prometheus-adapter doesn't provide custom metric

Tags: prometheus, amazon-eks, hpa

I'm struggling with configurartion HPA using Prometheus.
My goal is to scale pod up and down with target cpu container utilization > 70 in 5 minus period.
Regular HPA configuration doesn't provide my opportunity to do this, bacause I'm on EKS.

I've deployed Prometheus and It's working. Also i've deployed its adapter and it also working.
I've cheked it by running

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

The answer contains a lot of metrics. Here is the start

```
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "services/node_xfs_inode_operation_missed",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespaces/kube_ingress_created",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
```

The problem is that answer doesn't contain my metric server_cpu. That i've put in prometheus adapter config map. Here is the full map.

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.yaml: |
    rules:
    - seriesQuery: 'server_cpu'
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: "server_cpu"
      metricsQuery: sum (irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"my-server-deployment|"}[5m]))
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^container_.*",container!="POD",namespace!="",pod!=""}'
      seriesFilters: []
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: ^container_(.*)_seconds_total$
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>,container!="POD"}[5m]))
        by (<<.GroupBy>>)
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^container_.*",container!="POD",namespace!="",pod!=""}'
      seriesFilters:
      - isNot: ^container_.*_seconds_total$
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: ^container_(.*)_total$
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>,container!="POD"}[5m]))
        by (<<.GroupBy>>)
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^container_.*",container!="POD",namespace!="",pod!=""}'
      seriesFilters:
      - isNot: ^container_.*_total$
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: ^container_(.*)$
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>,container!="POD"}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
    - seriesQuery: '{namespace!="",__name__!~"^container_.*"}'
      seriesFilters:
      - isNot: .*_total$
      resources:
        template: <<.Resource>>
      name:
        matches: ""
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
    - seriesQuery: '{namespace!="",__name__!~"^container_.*"}'
      seriesFilters:
      - isNot: .*_seconds_total
      resources:
        template: <<.Resource>>
      name:
        matches: ^(.*)_total$
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[5m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
    - seriesQuery: '{namespace!="",__name__!~"^container_.*"}'
      seriesFilters: []
      resources:
        template: <<.Resource>>
      name:
        matches: ^(.*)_seconds_total$
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(rate(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}[5m])) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus-adapter
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: prometheus
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-11T08:53:58Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v0.10.0
    helm.sh/chart: prometheus-adapter-4.1.1
  name: prometheus-adapter
  namespace: prometheus
  resourceVersion: "1964528"
  uid: 834fc1a9-be88-4d96-b31b-83abab9d7a5f
```

Now I have no ideas what did I wrong.

I've tried a lot of different configurations of config map, but it doesn't help me.

As a result I expect to see my metric availible for using in HPA configuration.